# Practical Best Practice Questions

Tags: discussion

There are a number of questions of similar type that get asked here:

- [How many conditions in an "if clause" is acceptable?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/how-many-conditions-in-an-if-clause-is-acceptable)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/using-catching-exceptions-to-improve-readability-good-or-bad
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/is-saving-markup-to-the-data-layer-good-practice
- [Is this a "pythonic" method of executing functions based on the values of a tuple?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5517/is-this-a-pythonic-method-of-executing-functions-based-on-the-values-of-a-tupl)

My read on [Best practice questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/best-practice-questions) and the FAQ is that none of these questions are on-topic for code review. However, at least one of the questions was migrated to code review after asking a mod who indicated it was acceptable.

So questions:

1. Are these on-topic for Code Review?
2. If not, do they belong on StackOverflow or Programmers?
3. Do we want to go back and move all of these questions to the appropriate site, or leave well enough alone and only apply the policy to newer questions.

Answer (score 6):

For the most part the the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) seems a bit fuzzy on this matter, but I think the telling line is the first.

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for **sharing code from projects you are working on** for peer review.

<sub>(emphasis existing)</sub>

If the question is using example/place holder, then I would say it's off topic.
If the question is using actual code and just asking if it complies with best practice then I would say on topic.

Compliance with best practice is in the list of things that may be commented on and the OP is allowed to ask for a focus on a particular type of critique, though the answer may still comment on other aspects.

Your third example seems on-topic based on my interpretation of the FAQ. If we decide that we don't want such questions then we should probably update the FAQ to be a little clearer on the matter.

Comment: See also http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/267/do-stylistic-questions-belong-here-or-on-programmers-se

Comment: My read on the third question was the OP wasn't looking for a review of his code, but only an answer to his specific best-practice question. That's why I see it as off-topic.