# The CodeReview FAQ needs clarification of its intent around "best practices" questions

Tags: discussion

The [CodeReview FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) is confusing to me regarding *best practices* as a topic because on the one hand it says:

> If you are looking for specific feedback about…
>
> Best practices and design pattern usage in your code

and on the other hand it says...

> and your question is *not* about …
>
> Tools, best practices, improving, or conducting code reviews

I compared this to the [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) which did not even mention *best practices* and decided since it was covered in the CodeReview FAQ I would ask [my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127447/42759) over there.

Then somebody decided to migrate my question over to Programmers.

My question was not just about *best practices*, but specifically *best practice in my code*; albeit what I posted was a simplified version of the code so that it would be focused on exactly the issue at hand regarding explicit versus implicit line joining. To me this would seem to fit clearly within the scope defined in the CodeReview FAQ.

I'm fine with my question being moved to Programmers if it is better suited for that forum, but in that case the CodeReview FAQ should be clarified to explain which kinds of *best practices* questions fit in CodeReview and which kind fit elsewhere (a specific pointer to that other place would be helpful). Also, it would probably be a good idea to update the Elsewhere FAQ to clearly state that *best practices* fits the inclusion criteria.

Comment: Oops, thanks for migrating... I meant to post to meta.codereview rather than meta.stackoverflow... but now this question is "disembodied"... I am somehow no longer the owner or connected to this question. Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Similiar previously asked questions:

1. [Best practice questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/best-practice-questions).
2. [Confused by FAQ](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/confused-by-faq)

> My question was not just about best practices, but specifically best
>   practice in my code;

Your question seemed to be very general about all python code. i.e. there is nothing that it specific to your code. Thus its a question about best practices not about best practices in your code.

> albeit what I posted was a simplified version of the code so that it
>   would be focused on exactly the issue at hand regarding explicit
>   versus implicit line joining.

At code review, we review your code. We are all about the code. We want to improve code. So if you don't show your actual code, your question is automatically off-topic. We want to look at code and generally find ways to improve it. We don't discuss what the general best practice is, we point out where you've failed to follow it.

Seeing as this has come up a few times, the FAQ needs some help. Last time it came up I wasn't moderator, but now I am, so I can actually do something about it. Yay!